# What is the most concise way to array a series of string variables that may be empty

Tags: c#, arrays, string, params-keyword

I need to array an ad-hoc set of strings like this

```
string a = null;
string b = "include me";
string c = string.Empty;
string d = "me too!";
```

without including null or empty strings. I know I can use a child function and `params`:

```
private List<string> GetUniqueKeys(params string[] list)
{
    var newList = new List<string>();
    foreach (string s in list)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
            newList.Add(s);
    }
    return newList;
}

///

return this.GetUniqueKeys(a, b, c, d).ToArray();
```

but is there any simpler way to do this that I'm not seeing?

**EDIT**: Sorry about that, happy to vote up the first LINQer, but I should have specified that I was trying to get rid of the child method altogether, not simplify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No Child Function**

The shortest way you can do this without a child function is the following:

```
var a = new string[] { a, b, c, d }.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s));
```

**With Child Function**

However, I would recommend using your child function:

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetUniqueKeys(params string[] list)
{
    return list.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(s));
}
```

**Extension Method**

Alternatively, if you're really looking for other options... you could create an extension method:

```
public static List<string> AddIfNotEmpty(this List<string> list, params string[] items)
{
    list.AddRange(items.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));

    return list;
}
```

Then use it like such:

```
var list = new List<string>().AddIfNotEmpty(a, b, c, d);
```

And add other items later:

```
list.AddIfNotEmpty("new item", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 4):

If the input strings are enumerable, you can use linq.

```
var result = stringList.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToArray();
```

Comment: obviously you could use any criteria here.

Comment: @lincoln Please see edit--I thought I was being clear when I said "I know I can use a child function..." that I hoped to avoid it altogether but I obvously was not.

Comment: @downwitch `new string[] { a, b, c, d }.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))`

Comment: @DavidSherret Yeah I was trying to avoid that kind of thing too

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<string> GetUniqueKeys(params string[] list)
{
    var newList = new List<string>();
    newList.AddRange(list.Where(str => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)));

    return newList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Child method..

```
private List<string> GetUniqueKeys(params string[] list)
{
    return list.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToList();
}
```

Without Child method..

```
string a = null;
string b = "include me";
string c = string.Empty;
string d = "me too!";

string[] lst = { a, b, c, d };
var uniqueLst = lst.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToList(); //Or ToArray();
```

I recommend to use child method with `params`.